# Supporting Multiple screen sizes Android AIR by making stage MAX resolution

Tags: actionscript-3, air, screen, flash-cs6

Hey everyone so this is not a duplicate! The question I have is if i make the stage width and height of my Android AIR 4.0 Application using FLASH CS6 to say 1080x1920 and make all my movieClips etc... fit the stage. Will it then be able to fit all lower screen sizes and scale automatically? instead of having to create multiple XML files and create a different size image for all available screen sizes?

I don't know a really good method of doing this, so i thought that this might be a logical approach since it's the largest possible already can't it just shrink down to all devices? I tested on my small screen and the only problem I am having is it not filling the whole width of the screen.

But then I Add this line of code in my Constructor and everything fits perfectly:

```
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;
        stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

If you follow the Flex model, it's the other way around. Flex apps are generally built for the lowest screen density (**not** resolution) and scale upwards. The sizing and placements respond naturally to the screen size. At each screen density range, a new set of images are used and a new multiplier is used for all of the sizes and positions.

So let's look at it this way. In Flex, there are a set of DPI ranges. 120 (generally ignored), 160, 240, 320, 480, and 640. Every device uses a single one of those settings. Take the iPhone. You build for 160, but the iPhone is 320dpi. So all of the values you use, built for 160dpi, are doubled for your app on the iPhone. You use images twice the size, too.

For most of my apps, I have at least four different sizes (one each for 160, 240, 320, and 480 dpi ranges) of every single image in my project. The images only scale if I don't have an image for the dpi range. The goal should be to *never* scale any images, up or down. In each range, the images remain the same size at all times and the only thing that changes is the positioning of them.

Now, I've used Flex as my example here, since the layout engine it uses is extremely thorough and well thought out, but it is entirely possible to build a simple system for this in AS3 as well (I did it last year with relative ease).

The biggest thing you need to do is forget about screen resolution. In this day and age, especially with Android where there are hundreds of different screens in use, screen size and resolution are irrelevant. Screen density, on the other hand, is *everything*

Comment: Very interesting. So in conclusion I should be more concerned with the Density? Ill have to do some research on that then. I wasn't ven concerned with that until not. Also i read about that method of creating at least 4 different sizes for very image but that seems so time consuming and increase in application size. Also I don't really understand how to go about doing that and implementing it in my xml. But thanks for all the information I have a lot of pondering to do. Wish it was more easier. But being a beginner it's hard.

Comment: I created my first application and published to the Google Play Store already. I just forgot about multiple support for screen sizes and I keep getting a lot of feedback about this with larger devices such as note 3 etc...